# Python Selenium : download method with javascript:__dopostback not working in all websites

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, dom-events

I tried to use selenium technology with google chrome/chrome driver in Python to download a file at the url :

1. https://tso.nbpower.com/Public/en/system_information_archive.aspx (the file is downloaded when "Get Data" button is clicked).
   While inspecting the button we can see that behind it is a « javascript__dopostback » command launched.
2. I also tried to download a file at the following link : https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=0&type=0&season=2020&month=0&season1=2020&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0&startdate=2020-01-01&enddate=2020-12-31
   where there is a « Export Data » button with behind the same « javascript__dopostback » command.

**While using the exact same code it is not working in website 1. Anyone has an idea what I missed ?**

Here is the code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time


from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException   

def main():

    options = Options()
    options.headless = True

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

    driver.get("https://tso.nbpower.com/Public/en/system_information_archive.aspx")
    # driver.get("https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=0&type=0&season=2020&month=0&season1=2020&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0&startdate=2020-01-01&enddate=2020-12-31")
    # Above in comments url of the 2nd website (working)

    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    xpath = '//*[@id="ctl00_cphMainContent_lbGetData"]'
    # xpath = '//*[@id="LeaderBoard1_cmdCSV"]'
    # Above in comments xpath of the 2nd website button to download file (working)

    button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
    print(button)
    print(button.is_enabled())
    print(button.is_displayed())
    print(button.is_selected())
    test = button.click()

    driver.close()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Additional information : Google Chrome 88.0.4324.150 is used with the compatible Chromedriver ; and the OS is a Linux without graphical interface.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? When doing that manually I see on the first site the data is presented on the browser while on site 2 some Excel file is downloaded

Comment: It is working manually in both websites but with selenium only on website 2. But not in website 1 : (

Comment: i.e. the download is working on website 2 but not in website 1.

Comment: anyone has an idea why it is not working in website 1 ?